# Return the id of inserted value with unique id in Postresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I inserted dataset into a table with unique index. I need to get ids of inserted values.

```
 INSERT INTO table_subject_topics_exams (name_of_subject, section, topic, subtopic)
 VALUES 
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number Sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Geometric Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Geometric Progression'),
 ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING returning ids_of_subject_section;
```

the  database I get:

```
3 "Algebra" "Mathematics" "Progressions" "Number sequences"
33 "Algebra" "Mathematics" "Progressions" "Arithmetic progression"
37 "Algebra" "Mathematics" "Progressions" "Geometric progression"
```

the first column is ids numbers. My aim is to get

```
3 (12 times)
33 (4 times)
37 (2 times)
```

How should I make my query?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `returning` clause:

```
with i as (
      insert into table_subject_topics_exams . . .
      . . .
      returning *  -- or whatever columns you want
     )
select *
from i;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a9f2ba7d0476d570cc0205615e0263de) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

If you wanted all the original values, then you would need to put them into a "table" and join them back:

```
with vals as (
      select *
      from (values ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number Sequences'),
                   ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
                   . . .
           ) v(name_of_subject, section, topic, subtopic)
     ),
     i as (
      insert into table_subject_topics_exams (name_of_subject, section, topic, subtopic)
          select name_of_subject, section, topic, subtopic
          from vals
          on conflict do nothing
          returning ids_of_subject_section
     )
select v.*, i.ids_of_subject_section
from vals join
     i
     using (name_of_subject, section, topic, subtopic);
```

Comment: The CTE isn't really needed

Comment: I poot queery in brackets.But it does not work at all

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . That's true, but I prefer to separate the DML action from returning results.

Comment: @ВладимирКузовкин . . . I added a db<>fiddle with the returning clause.

Comment: you return 4 rows in table.But as the result I want to have ids of existinf values in table

Comment: If there are 30 values, I want to have 30 ids

Comment: It gives you the ids from the values that are inserted. If you tried to insert values that already exist, you won't get an id for these values because these values are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This query does an INSERT and a SELECT on the input to create an aggregation:

```
WITH i AS (
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        (VALUES
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number Sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Geometric Progression' ),
            ( 'Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Geometric Progression' ) 
        ) sub ( name_of_subject, section, topic, subtopic ) 
    ),
    dml AS ( 
        INSERT INTO table_subject_topics_exams ( name_of_subject, section, topic, subtopic ) 
        SELECT * 
        FROM i 
        ON CONFLICT 
        DO NOTHING 
        RETURNING * 
) 
SELECT  ids_of_subject_section
    ,   COUNT ( * ) 
FROM
    i
    LEFT JOIN dml USING ( name_of_subject, section, topic, subtopic ) 
GROUP BY
    ids_of_subject_section;
```